# What can I do to reduce the file size of an .exe created from a Python script?

Tags: python, file, exe

I have created a little Python script and now I am creating an .exe using pyinstaller.
This works perfectly fine but I wondered if there's anything I can do to reduce the file size of the output .exe.
I think the large file size may come from the amount of libraries I used in my project:

1. os
2. time
3. sys
4. subprocess
5. json
6. math

   ...

Is there anything I can do to reduce the file size? Right now it's 32mB with about 64kB of Code I have actually written myself.
Why is my .exe so large?

Comment: Your executable includes _the entire Python interpreter_; the specific Python libraries you use beyond that add very little. If you want small, standalone binaries, use a language that isn't interpreted, or require the user to install the interpreter separately.

Comment: I was thinking about that. So this file size is inevitable?

Comment: If you're using pyinstaller and want your binaries to be standalone, yes, it's inevitable. Same if you were building a Java program but didn't want to require your user to already have a JVM.

Comment: (If you're targeting Windows systems new enough that all users are guaranteed to have the CLR, think about using IronPython instead of CPython).

Comment: In short there is not way to reduce its size it will be as it is.

Comment: Yes I know, so in C or C++ for example this code would be much smaller wouldn't it?

Comment: I'd never suggest anyone use C or C++ in new development. Rust is probably what I'd suggest in terms of a modern language with reasonably small executable sizes (a lot of development I do is in Go, but it's not particularly good about file sizes either). But yes, C binaries can be much smaller.

Comment: Interesting but I don't know Rust, C/C++ Python and Java appear to be the only languages I know fairly well, so I was just wondering

Comment: BTW, if your users _do_ already have JVMs installed, Jython becomes another option. (I work in security, so the reasons for my bias against C -- despite it having been my primary / go-to language 20 years ago -- should be pretty clear; C++ has those same problems, plus a whole boatload of other design-by-committee issues on top).